# Logback configuration error detected: RedHat Jboss EAP 7.2

Tags: spring, maven, deployment, jboss7.x

After adding the war generated from spring boot application to the deployments.

I got this error after deploying.

{"WFLYCTL0080: Les services ont échoué" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."administration-0.0.1.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:71 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [contextListener] java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [application-profile_IS_UNDEFINED.properties].
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@65d93a4d - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@b60b639 - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:71 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [contextListener] java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [application-profile_IS_UNDEFINED.properties].
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@65d93a4d - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@b60b639 - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:71 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [contextListener] java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [application-profile_IS_UNDEFINED.properties].
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@65d93a4d - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@b60b639 - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:71 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [contextListener] java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [application-profile_IS_UNDEFINED.properties].
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@65d93a4d - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@b60b639 - Failed to get charset [charset_IS_UNDEFINED] java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: charset_IS_UNDEFINED"}}

pom.xml for the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gti.sbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>administration</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Administration</name>
    <description>Administration</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.gti</groupId>
        <artifactId>sbe</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <gti.shared>1.0.0</gti.shared>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gti</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${gti.shared}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.gti.administration.Application</mainClass>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>        
     </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml for the whole app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gti</groupId>
    <artifactId>sbe</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>SBE</name>
    <description>Refonte SBE</description>
    <modules>
        <module>Administration</module>
        <module>Shared</module>
        <module>TransfertVirement</module>
        <module>interfacage</module>
        <module>Domiciliation</module>
        <module>Divers</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <arg-resolver.version>2.6.2</arg-resolver.version>
        <hibernate-52.version>2.12.1</hibernate-52.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jwt.version>3.18.2</jwt.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <modelmapper.version>2.4.4</modelmapper.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.5.5</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.oracle.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.oracle.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: Data -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>`enter code here`
            <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.oracle.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-52.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Specification Arg Resolver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>${arg-resolver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot: Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>development</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>development</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>production</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>staging</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Note : I already added this to application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path = /@artifactId@ 

server.servlet-path = /*

spring.application.name = @name@
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Environment: RedHat Jboss EAP 7.2  , Spring boot 2.5.5 , JDK 11, Windows 11 Pro x64.

Thanks in advance.